# How can I create a pod that can be reached by another pod via hostname in minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have two simple applications that I have to deploy in Minikube on two different pods. The two applications must communicate via REST calls, so I need an IP address. How can I create a Minikube pod that I can reach locally via a hostname such as http://name:port without writing the IP address?

Comment: You should put your Pods behind [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). Services will allow you to access each application by DNS using the FQDN `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example` (or simply `service-name` if the pods are in the same namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Kubernetes-Approach would be adding an [Service-Layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) around the Pods (the instances) of your application. To do this, write a YAML-Spec like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp # << Replace with a matching Label
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: # << Replace with a matching Port
```

After you applied your changes `kubectl apply -f <FILENAME>`, you can access all services fulfilling the specified label-selector across all namespaces inside your cluster by calling this DNS-Name: `my-service.<NAMESPACE>.svc`